# How to get correct data from HTTP Request

Tags: java, http, get, request

I'm trying to get my user information from stackoverflow api using a simple HTTP request with GET method in Java.

This code I had used before to get another HTTP data using GET method without problems:

```
    URL obj;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
    String url = "http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?inname=HCarrasko&site=stackoverflow";
        try {
        obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        con.setRequestMethod("GET");
        int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
        System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }

        in.close();
        System.out.println(response.toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But in this case I'm getting just stranger symbols when I print the `response` var, like this:

```
�mRM��0�+�N!���FZq�\�pD�z�:V���JX���M��̛yO^���뾽�g�5J&� �9�YW�%c`do���Y'��nKC38<A�&It�3��6a�,�,]���`/{�D����>6�Ɠ��{��7tF ��E��/����K���#_&�yI�a�v��uw}/�g�5����TkBTķ���U݊c���Q�y$���$�=ۈ��ñ���8f�<*�Amw�W�ـŻ��X$�>'*QN�?�<v�ݠ FH*��Ҏ5����ؔA�z��R��vK���"���@�1��ƭ5��0��R���z�ϗ/�������^?r��&�f��-�OO7���������Gy�B���Rxu�#:0�xͺ}�\�����
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The content is likely GZIP encoded/compressed. The following is a general snippet that I use in all of my Java-based client applications that utilize HTTP, which is intended to deal with this exact problem:

```
// Read in the response
// Set up an initial input stream:
InputStream inputStream = fetchAddr.getInputStream(); // fetchAddr is the HttpURLConnection

// Check if inputStream is GZipped
if("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(fetchAddr.getContentEncoding())){
    // Format is GZIP
    // Replace inputSteam with a GZIP wrapped stream
    inputStream = new GZIPInputStream(inputStream);
}else if("deflate".equalsIgnoreCase(fetchAddr.getContentEncoding())){
    inputStream = new InflaterInputStream(inputStream, new Inflater(true));
} // Else, we assume it to just be plain text

BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
String inputLine;
StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
// ... and from here forward just read the response...
```

This relies on the following imports: `java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream`; `java.util.zip.Inflater`; and `java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream`.